# Print to PDF via AirPrint

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I'm building an app using Cordova and I used this Plug-in to print the content of an HTML page. I would try to print this to a PDF, not using AirPrint printer.
How can I do it (also by modifying .m and .h files in the Plugin Folder)?
Here's the plugin I've used: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/PrintPlugin
Thank you!

```
 var html = document.getElementById("printHTML").innerHTML;
window.plugins.printPlugin.print(
                                 html,
                                 function(result) {
                                 alert("Printing successful");
                                 },
                                 function(result) {
                                 if (!result.available){
                                 alert("Printing is not available");
                                 }
                                 else{
                                 //Localised error description
                                 alert(result.error);
                                 }
                                 });
```

Comment: There is not PDF printer in iOS and the plugin you provided only allows printing to AirPrinter. In native code you could access `UIKit` `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData `: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW1

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if you find a better answer as I am looking for the same solution. In the meantime, what I have done is open up a browser in a new window (skip the plugin all together) and run the html-document through pdfcrowd.com. Then I use airprint directly from the browser.